# How do I turn off automatic update checking for plugins in Mars Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

How do I turn off automatic update checking for plugins in Mars Eclipse?

I have a plugin, a decompiler that keeps popping up an alert saying there's a newer version available.  This message pops up every time I start Eclipse.

This is in spite of the fact that I have disabled "Automatic Updates" in:
Install/Update | Automatic Updates | turned off.

Any ideas of how to turn off this notification?  It's very annoying.

I am using this version of JD-Core: 2.9.0.r20160620180

Here's what I see:
[image]

I have NOT selected updates to be checked:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue recently, I'm assuming you're using the [Java Class Decompiler](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-class-decompiler) plugin which was updated to version 3.0.0 last week.

You can disable the automatic update checking by going to *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Decompiler*. In the *Startup* section, unselect the *Check for major version updates* box, as shown below:

[image: Disable Eclipse decompiler plugin updates]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't see this option in my preferences window?  Maybe you have a different plugin version than I do?  I have 2.9.0.r20160620180.

Ironically, perhaps I have to update to a newer plugin version to get this option to turn off notifications of new plugins?

I was hoping there was a way to do this for ALL of the Eclipse plugins, not just this one?

Comment: Apparently the update checker does not work correctly in version 2.9.0. It was fixed in version 2.9.1, according to the following Github issue: https://github.com/cnfree/Eclipse-Class-Decompiler/issues/7